# Invalid emails are missing .com at the end, how to add?

Tags: sql

I have around 1,600 emails that are missing .com at the end of the email. How can I add the missing .com to all the 1,600 emails?

For example the email address in our database is like **colondoris5@gmail** and I need to add ***.com*** at the end of all the gmail, yahoo, hotmail and ymail accounts.

This is my select statement that generate the results showing all the incorrect emails:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
C.CustomerID,
C.BAN_ADSL_TN,
C.LandlinePhoneNumber,
C.MobilePhoneNumber,
C.EmailAddress,
C.CreatedBy,
C.ModifiedBy,
C.CreateDate
FROM dbo.Customers AS C
WHERE NOT C.EmailAddress LIKE '%_@__%.__%'
  AND C.EmailAddress != ''
  AND PATINDEX('%[^a-z,0-9,@,.,_,\-]%', C.EmailAddress) = 0
ORDER BY C.CreateDate DESC
```

Comment: Where are you checking for those domains?

Comment: The other answers are fine for the question you asked, but I'd be wary of the complexity with email validation. Ex. here's the first ~500 characters of a ~6000 character regular expression for it: (?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ 
\t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\0
31]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append .com to the column EmailAddress:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
C.CustomerID,
C.BAN_ADSL_TN,
C.LandlinePhoneNumber,
C.MobilePhoneNumber,
(case when c.EmailAddress like '%hotmail%' OR
       c.EmailAddress like '%gmail%' OR
       c.EmailAddress like '%yahoo%' OR
       c.EmailAddress like '%ymail%'
  then c.EmailAddress + '.com'
  else c.EmailAddress
  end)
C.CreatedBy,
C.ModifiedBy,
C.CreateDate
FROM dbo.Customers AS C
WHERE NOT C.EmailAddress LIKE '%_@__%.__%'
  AND C.EmailAddress != ''
  AND PATINDEX('%[^a-z,0-9,@,.,_,\-]%', C.EmailAddress) = 0
ORDER BY C.CreateDate DESC
```

Comment: Just tack on logic that checks for those specific domains in the OP. A Netscape email would need '.net'

Comment: @dfundako Thanks, I was responding to another post and wasn't paying enough attention, thank you for the comment. Fixing my answer now

Comment: @dfundako would you be able to help with the logic for specific domains?

Comment: @KSingh I would just check on the server side code whether the email address is valid before even submitting it to the database. But if you don't want to go that route, you could do the check inside your sql procedure or statement to make sure the address is valid.

Comment: I was thinking of adding a constraint on the email column in customers table so user won't be able to enter the invalid email.

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

```
(case when c.EmailAddress not like '%.com' and
           c.EmailAddress not like '%.edu' and
           c.EmailAddress not like '%.org' and
           c.EmailAddress not like '%.gov'  -- and maybe more!
      then c.EmailAddress + '.com'
      else c.EmailAddress
 end)
```

You may be making a big assumption that the top-level domain is `.com`.  Many others are in common use.

Note that your query is finding other issues with the email address apart from the missing top-level domain.  And it is going to miss emails where the domain name consists of more than two parts but is missing a top-level domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy that the records returned by your `select` statement represent the invalid records, you can simply create an `update` using the same `where` clause.

```
UPDATE Customers
SET EmailAdress = EmailAddress + '.com'
WHERE NOT EmailAddress LIKE '%_@__%.__%' AND EmailAddress != '' AND PATINDEX('%[^a-z,0-9,@,.,_,\-]%', C.EmailAddress) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest method would be

```
update e
set emailaddress = emailaddress + '.com'   -- or concat(emailaddress,'.com')
 from emaildb e
where charindex('.com',emailaddress) = 0   -- only looking for no .com suffix
```